# Why does multiprocessing Pool instantiation work in one program but get a ImportError in another?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use the multiprocessing package and implement a Pool but am getting the error:

> ImportError: This platform lacks a functioning sem_open
>   implementation, therefore, the required synchronization primitives
>   needed will not function, see issue 3770.

However, if I write another separate test program, I am able to implement multiprocessing and create a pool object. Why would it work in one program and not in another.  Here is my test program that works:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import types
import copy_reg


def _pickle_method(method):
    func_name = method.im_func.__name__
    obj = method.im_self
    cls = method.im_class
    return _unpickle_method, (func_name, obj, cls)


def _unpickle_method(func_name, obj, cls):
    for cls in cls.mro():
        try:
            func = cls.__dict__[func_name]
        except KeyError:
          pass
        else:
            break

    return func.__get__(obj, cls)


class Myclass(object):
    def mult(self):
        d = Data()
        # This works in this test program but this call in my actual
        # program doesn't work.  The actual program is to large and 
        # complex to paste into this posting.   
        pool = Pool(processes=4)

        result = pool.map(self.myfunc, zip(d.lx, d.ly))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    def call_mult(self):
        self.mult()

    def myfunc(self, elements):
        x, y = elements
        v = 0
        for z in xrange(x):
            v += z

        v = v * y
        v = v - x

        return v


class Data(object):
    def __init__(self):
        lx = []
        ly = []
        for x in range(100, 1000):
            for y in range(10, 500):
                lx.append(x)
                ly.append(y)

        self.lx = lx
        self.ly = ly


if __name__ == "__main__":
    copy_reg.pickle(types.MethodType, _pickle_method, _unpickle_method)
    myobj = Myclass()
    myobj.call_mult()
```

I tried to make the test program structured as closely to my actual program as possible.  This is why I have all of the objects and pickling functions in place.  This way I can bind a method from an object to the muliprocessing map method.  In any case, I'm just wondering why a call to Pool would result in the Import error in one case but not in another?  I'll try to get a smaller version of my actual program that fails that I can post.

Entire stack trace looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gxh6506/dev/fpc/srxfpc.py", line 137, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/gxh6506/dev/fpc/srxfpc.py", line 95, in main
    pool = Pool(processes=3)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 232, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 138, in __init__
    self._setup_queues()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 233, in _setup_queues
    from .queues import SimpleQueue
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .synchronize import Lock, BoundedSemaphore, Semaphore, Condition
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 59, in <module>
    " function, see issue 3770.")
ImportError: This platform lacks a functioning sem_open implementation, therefore, the required synchronization primitives needed will not function, see issue 3770.
```

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace and which operating system you use? This should fail simply by `import multiprocessing` (its `__init__.py` imports `multiprocessing.synchronize` which checks for `SemLock` in the `_mulitprocessing` C extension). I don't see how some programs succeed while others fail on the exact same machine. Anything different in the exec environment, like a virtualenv, a locally built python?

Comment: OS I'm using is RHEL 7.3

Comment: How are you running your two programs? Are you sure they're getting run by the same interpreter? The exception you describe is telling you that `multiprocessing.synchronize` can't get access to the C system calls it needs for its implementation. That seems like a very unlikely thing to change, just from running a different Python script. It's much more likely if you're running a completely different interpreter too.

Comment: Yes, I am.  I am running them in a PyCharm IDE and they are run in the same project so I know I am using the same environment and interpreter.